# sending email with attached pictures in android (solution)

Tags: android, email, android-emulator, mms

the image is stored in android sd card

I got the solution we need to specify

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

in manifest and the working code is:

```
String _path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/mapp/test.jpeg";
File file = new File( _path );
Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile( file );

if(file.exists())
{

//final ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
//final int result = connMgr.startUsingNetworkFeature( ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE,Phone.FEATURE_ENABLE_MMS);

    Toast.makeText(context,"exists",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {"abc@cde.com"});
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"World Toyata(via Android App");
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,outputFileUri);
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Problem Area Image");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, ""));
}
else
{
    Toast.makeText(context,"SD CARD Required ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

            }
```

Comment: Hi friends i am waiting for u r reply plz help to find a way to attach pictures to android email

Comment: I got the solution we need to specify

Comment: You should not need permission send_sms for email

Comment: @Heiko Rupp, Yes u r right...

Answer (score 0):

Ramesh - I found value in your example but also found that it is was not necessary for me to have the permission android.permission.SEND_SMS.

I am wondering if it is necessary to have 
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Email:"));

where you specify "Email:".

Comment: Yes you can add String data  using startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Email:")); using above line, in my case i am including my client name other details i.e why i left black space, but anyway it will be sent as a email  because we are specifying Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL at  sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {"abc@cde.com"});
so it will be an email only.  as you told the permission SEND_SMS is not required, sorry for my fault..